# Running a .py file in python that requires input

Tags: python

the question I have is really a simple one, and maybe the issue is just myself not knowing the correct parameters for python with Linux.

The file I am running uses input from the operator both to run the program, and also to get the information to convert, which I will place below:

```
    Initial_LonH = float(input("\nEnter RA's Hour >>> "));
    Initial_LonM = float(input("\nEnter RA's Minute >>> "));
    Initial_LonS = float(input("\nEnter Ra's Second >>> "));
    Initial_LatH = float(input("\nEnter Dec's Hour >>> "));
    Initial_LatM = float(input("\nEnter Dec's Minute >>> "));
    Initial_LatS = float(input("\nEnter Dec's Second >>> "));
```

The issue when I run this in python as "python GalaxyConverter.py, the following error appears:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "GalaxyConverter.py", line 105, in <module>
     input_Runner = str(input("\nDo you wish to convert Right Ascension and Declination into Cartesian?"
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
```

It seems the issue is that the file does not know to take the command I put into the terminal as input for the python file. May I ask what I should do to fix this?

The Entire Code is below:

```
from math import radians, sin, cos, sqrt, asin, atan

Minute_Con = 60;
Second_Con = 3600;
DT_Radians = 0.0174539252;
RT_Degrees = 57.29577951;
Radi_Verse = 879829141200000000000000;
WRunner = True


def HMS_Expand_Lon(LongitudeH, LongitudeM, LongitudeS):
    ##{
    print("\n The Right Ascension starts as " + str(LongitudeH) + ":" + str(LongitudeM) + "." + str(LongitudeS));
    LongitudeM = LongitudeM/Minute_Con;
    LongitudeS = LongitudeS/Second_Con;
    LongitudeHMS = LongitudeH + LongitudeM + LongitudeS;
    LongitudeHMS = LongitudeHMS * 15;
    print("\n The Right Ascension becomes " + str(LongitudeHMS));
    return LongitudeHMS
    ##}

def HMS_Expand_Lat(LatitudeH, LatitudeM, LatitudeS):
    ##{
    print("\n The Declination starts as " + str(LatitudeH) + ":" + str(LatitudeM) + "." + str(LatitudeS));
    LatitudeM = LatitudeM/Minute_Con;
    LatitudeS = LatitudeS/Second_Con;
    LatitudeHMS = LatitudeH + LatitudeM + LatitudeS;
    LatitudeHMS = LatitudeHMS * 15;
    print("\n The Declination becomes " + str(LatitudeHMS));
    return LatitudeHMS
    ##}

def HMS_Convert_Lon(LongitudeHMS):
    ##{
    LongitudeRAD = LongitudeHMS * DT_Radians;
    print("\n The Right Ascension becomes " + str(LongitudeRAD));
    return LongitudeRAD
    ##}

def HMS_Convert_Lat(LatitudeHMS):
    ##{
    LatitudeRAD = LatitudeHMS * DT_Radians;
    print("\n The Declination becomes " + str(LatitudeRAD));
    return LatitudeRAD
    ##}

def RAD_Convert_Lon(LongitudeRAD, LatitudeRAD):
    ##{
    Con_Lon = LongitudeRAD * LongitudeRAD;
    Con_Lat = LatitudeRAD * LatitudeRAD;
    Con_Lat_Lon = sqrt(Con_Lat + Con_Lon);
    print("\n The Right Ascension becomes " + str(Con_Lat_Lon));
    return Con_Lat_Lon
    ##}

def RAD_Convert_Lat(LongitudeRAD, LatitudeRAD):
    ##{
    Con_Lon = LongitudeRAD;
    Con_Lat = LatitudeRAD;
    Con_Lon_Lat = atan(Con_Lon / Con_Lat);
    print("\n The Declination becomes " + str(Con_Lon_Lat));
    return Con_Lon_Lat
    ##}

def POL_Convert_Lon(LongitudePOL, LatitudePOL):
    ##{
    POL_Lon = LongitudePOL * cos(LatitudePOL);
    DEG_Lon = POL_Lon * RT_Degrees;
    print("\n X finally becomes " + str(DEG_Lon));
    return DEG_Lon
    ##}

def POL_Convert_Lat(LongitudePOL, LatitudePOL):
    ##{
    POL_Lat = LongitudePOL * sin(LatitudePOL);
    DEG_Lat = POL_Lat * RT_Degrees;
    print("\n Y finally becomes " + str(DEG_Lat));
    return DEG_Lat
    ##}

def main():
    ##{
    Initial_LonH = float(input("\nEnter RA's Hour >>> "));
    Initial_LonM = float(input("\nEnter RA's Minute >>> "));
    Initial_LonS = float(input("\nEnter Ra's Second >>> "));
    Initial_LatH = float(input("\nEnter Dec's Hour >>> "));
    Initial_LatM = float(input("\nEnter Dec's Minute >>> "));
    Initial_LatS = float(input("\nEnter Dec's Second >>> "));
    Lon_Expanded = HMS_Expand_Lon(Initial_LonH, Initial_LonM, Initial_LonS);
    Lat_Expanded = HMS_Expand_Lat(Initial_LatH, Initial_LatM, Initial_LatS);
    Lon_Converted = HMS_Convert_Lon(Lon_Expanded);
    Lat_Converted = HMS_Convert_Lat(Lat_Expanded);
    Lon_RAD = RAD_Convert_Lon(Lon_Converted, Lat_Converted);
    Lat_RAD = RAD_Convert_Lat(Lon_Converted, Lat_Converted);
    Lon_POL = POL_Convert_Lon(Lon_RAD, Lat_RAD);
    Lat_POL = POL_Convert_Lat(Lon_RAD, Lat_RAD);
    X_Scaled = Lon_POL / Radi_Verse;
    Y_Scaled = Lat_POL / Radi_Verse;
    print("\n   To scale of the theoretical length of universe, X = " + str(X_Scaled));
    print("\n   To scale of the theoretical length of the universe, Y = " + str(Y_Scaled));
    ##}


while WRunner == True:
    input_Runner = input("\nDo you wish to convert Right Ascension and Declination into Cartesian?"
                             "\nif so, please type yes, if not, please type no >>> ");
    if input_Runner == "yes":
        main();
    if input_Runner != "yes":
        break
```

Comment: Which python version you are using ?

Comment: Where I can see code for `GalaxyConverter.py`? Its your file?

Comment: Add more code. We need to see the "GalaxyConverter.py"

Comment: @LilyCollins Try to use `raw_input` for when you want a string. That could help solve your problem. Also, give us the applicable lines of the program.

Comment: Oh, and you have colons at the end of your lines. Don't do that ;)

Comment: Alright I edited to have all of the code present. Also for the use of semi colons it's just a habit I used from c++ and gml.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, you can just use `input` in your example, it can input strings.
But in python 2, the same function is `raw_input`.

`input` function in Python 2 is equals to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`, it will evaluate input string as a Python expression.

Obviously your running python version is python 2, but I don't know what the code's python version is. But you need to modify all `input` to `raw_input` if it is python version is 2.

Ref:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input